# Will this.method2(); skip the return value?

Tags: java, methods

In this example of code. What will be read right after "this.method2();"? Will it jump to method2() before returning the returnedValue?

```
public int method1(int returnedValue) {
// Do something 
returnedValue = 1;
this.method2(); // Where will it go after this line?
return returnedValue;
}

public void method2() {
// Do something 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
sp.method2();
Stuff sp = new Stuff();
System.out.print(returned value);
}
```

Comment: That code will simply print `returned value`. `method1` and `method2` aren't invoked.

Comment: Miss typed. I don't really care about the end result, just which line it will go to after this.method2();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now your main method doesn't call method1, consider instead this main method :

```
public static void main(String[] args) { new Main().method1();}
```

Assuming `Main` is the main class, what will happen on this line :

```
this.method2();
```

Is that method2 gets called before method1 returns a value because you didn't call `return` before calling method2.

If method1 was defined like this :

```
public void method1(int returnedvalue)
{
    returnedvalue=1;
    return returnedvalue;
    this.method2();
}
```

Then method1 will return `returnedvalue` without calling method2(the above code is bad ofcourse as `this.method2()` is unreachable).

After method2 finishes and returns, method1 execute the next statement which is `return returnedvalue`, it will return and execution continues in `main`.

As others said ofcourse, if exception was raised in method2 without being caught in it, The exception will propagate from method2 to method1, if method1 doesn't catch it it will propagate to main, if main doesn't catch it your app will crash :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running `method1()` it will call `method2()` and after it will finish running `method2()` it will continue `method1()` and will always return 1 (unless `method2()` will throw an exception).

But in this case, you are running `main()` which only prints `"returned value"` (String) and it's not calling `method1()` at any point.

Comment: OP isn't asking about the final result, apparently he's asking what happens on line `this.method2()`

Comment: @niceman correct. Does it read the returned value before calling the method or does it go to the method first?